# Getting all ERC721 transactions by an account

Tags: web3js, events, web3-providers

My approach here was to listen for *Transfer* event for a contract (e.g. Cryptokitties) filtered by the indexed *from* account.

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(kittyABI, kittyContractAddress, 
{from: account});
contract.events.Transfer(
  {filter: {from: account}}, fromBlock: 0},
  function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
```

The provider was at first Metamask. But that threw the error:
`The current provider doesn't support subscriptions`

So, I switched over to Infura. Infura had a similar problem unless you use websockets. The error went away and instead I started battling with timeout issue. After much effort, it seems like Infura websocket approach is still not perfectly functioning. So, I am thinking of rolling out my own geth node that simply runs that query. But before I do that, is there anything that I am missing? The problem shouldn't be this hard. I have seen a lot of ERC20 wallets afterall.

Comment: I don't think there's other way than reading events.

Answer (score 1):

A problem with [CryptoKitties implementation](https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code) of ERC721 is that events parameters are not indexed:

```
event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
event Approval(address owner, address approved, uint256 tokenId);
```

This causes filtering to be a more costly operation and to cause timeouts. Since it is part of the contract this cannot be changed and it will affect your own node.

The [final standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) have them indexed and you wil not have problem with new implementations that follow it.

For CryptoKitties a possible solution is to index all events in a database separately.

Comment: Oh, awesome. Good to know. I completely missed this. :)